# Deriving a function of $r$ (distance from the planet's center) for velocity for a projectile launched beyond escape velocity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, projectile, escape-velocity

This is my first post here, and I'm here because I'm rather confused. I'm doing some homework at the moment and the question is asking for a function $v(r)$ which represents the velocity of a projectile launched at √3 times escape velocity from a planet of mass $M$ with radius $R$ as a function of distance from the center of the planet $r$. What's confusing me is that we're required to have both the radius R and the distance from the center r in the answer. I'm just not exactly sure what I'm missing here though I'm sure it's something. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The escape velocity is the minimal velocity required to escape from the surface of a planet all the way to infinity. The surface is located at $R$ so the escape velocity is
$$v_{\text{esc}}(R)=\sqrt\frac{2GM}{R}.$$
You can derive this formula from conservation of energy. Now, given some initial velocity $v_0=\sqrt 3v_{\text{esc}}$ and some initial radius $r_0=R$ you can calculate the velocity at any other radius using conservation of energy:
$$E(v_0,r_0)=E(v,r)$$
I leave it to you to fill in the expression for the energy. Note that $R$ also enters this equation through $v_0$.

Comment: I got an expression though it was marked as wrong. Since initial and final energy are equal, I set the initial KE equal to (1/2)m[(sqrt3)(ve)]^2 and the gravitational PE to (GMm)/R, then the final was just (1/2)mv^2 and (GMm)/r. I substituted the equation you had for the escape velocity and isolated v to get sqrt(2(4GM/R)-(GM/r)) but what was marked wrong. Did I use the wrong equations here or something? I'm not sure how I keep messing up on this one.

Comment: @CreebPrimbleton Remember the gravitational PE is negative. May be this was marked wrong.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch you were right! I ended up not simplifying it enough and had it marked as wrong but at least the theory is there and it's just one question. Thank you!